# Import csv into QGIS using Python

Tags: python, csv, qgis

I am attempting to import a file into QGIS using a python script.  I'm having a problem getting it to accept the CRS.  Code so far

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

## ----1 Set file name here

InFlnm='Input.CSV'

## ---2 Set pathname here

InDrPth='G:/test'

## ---3 Build the file name and path for uri

InFlPth="file:///"+InDrPth+InFlnm

## ---4 Set import Sting here note only need to set x and y others come for free!

uri = InFlPth+"?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",","x","y")

## ---5 Load the points into a layer

bh = QgsVectorLayer(uri, InFlnm, "delimitedtext")

## ---6 Set the CRS (Not sure if this is working seems to?)

#### bh.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32365, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

## ---7 Display the layer in QGIS (Here I get a syntax error?)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(bh)

Now all the above works OK and QGIC prompts me for a CRS before executing the last line of the script to display the layer - as long as I comment-out step 6

However, if a attempt to set the CRS removing ### from step 6 I get a syntax error reporting on the last line that displays the points (Step 7).  Note sure what the trick is here - I'm pretty new to Python but know my way around some other programming lagnuages

Comment: can you verify that you read the values in the csv file? by printing the array or something.

Comment: Julius thanks for replying - I'm a bit embarrased now that I did not spot this syntax problem as it is quite obvious now you have pointed it out. However, when I now run the script, QGIS still prompts with the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" form to pick a CRS. I was expeccting that step 6 would stop this prompt as the CRS has been set for the imported CSV? A pointer in the right direction would be appreciated as I would like to get the script to load and display with points without human intervention.

Comment: hmm check bh.source() to see if you actually loaded something.

Comment: oh, and bh.isValid()

Comment: all of this was taken from reading the source http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html

Comment: Julius thanks again for replying and the suggestions. The source and isValid commands doshow something has been loaded and this seems to be further confirmed when the points load after I enter a CRS into the form.  The code is still the same (with syntax error corrected),  This it the first three lines of the point file which I am loading. (X,Y,Z,LENGTH,CU,S,AU,CUO,CU1,CU2,INDEX
559.26621306,2234.68248,0.0,,-999.0,,,,,,-999.0 
563.9107829,2175.4604286,0.0,,-999.0,,,,,,-999.0
568.55535274,2116.2383773,0.0,,-999.0,,,,,,-999.0). I'm using QGIS 2.1.0 perhaps I should try an older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to the final part of the problem at http://www.purplelinux.co.nz/.  I seems you need to suppress the form that prompts for the CRS.  So the my script now looks like

```
#--- Load a csv file and set CRS
#---1 Reference library
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

#---  2 Turn of the CRS dialog box
s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour")
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )

#--- 3 Set file name here
InFlnm='Test.csv'

#--- 4  Set pathname here
InDrPth='C:/_Work/PyQGIS/Test/'

#--- 5 Build file name an path for uri
InFlPth="file:///"+InDrPth+InFlnm

#---  6 Set import Sting here note only need to set x and y other come for free
uri = InFlPth+"?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",","x","y")

#--- 7 Load point layer
bh = QgsVectorLayer(uri, InFlnm, "delimitedtext")

#--- 8 Confirm something is loaded and valid
bh.isValid()

#--- 9 Set CRS
bh.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32365, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

#--- 10 Display the layer into QGIS (but it asks for CRS before displaying_
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(bh)

#--- 11 turn CRS dialog box back on again
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```

The imported points now display but I'm getting an error stating that the CRS is not recognised so suspect step 9 above is not working. I will post again if I can crack this problem otherwise I may have to be happy with the CRS default perhaps.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue with #9? I am having the same problem

Comment: I think somebody did solve this - check a following thread - I never did get back to this bit of fun...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the import example, really helpful for a geocoder python script I want to output a csv from into qgis. To solve your problem, add the crs in your uri line:

```
uri = InFlPth+"?crs=epsg:32365&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",","x","y")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a parenthesis missing from the end of  your --6 line of code.